# how do I insert a row into a custom table in Wordpress on s2member paid member activation?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom table my_users.

When a person signs up for membership to my site through s2member, I want to get the WordPress wp_user id and insert a new row into my_users.

Where do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
This will help you to save data in your custom table if you save table with wp prefix you can include that with table name.
<?php global $wpdb; 
// for get user id
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$arrayinsert = array('user_id'=>$user_id,'Type_User'=>get_current_user_role()); ?>
$insert_result = $wpdb->insert('my_users',$arrayinsert);
if ($insert_result) {
$varId  = $wpdb->insert_id;
} else {
echo "Error:". $wpdb->last_query; 
}
?>
```